# C# Declaring a 2D array without knowing its size from XML Document

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array, document

I would like to use a 2D array without knowing its size because the data is coming from an XML document. So how do I have to declare this array?

Here's my code:

```
List<string> eventList = new List<string>();
string[,] eventArray;

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(new StringReader(xmlData));

string xmlPathPattern = "//file//ALL_INSTANCES//instance";
XmlNodeList myNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xmlPathPattern);
foreach (XmlNode node in myNodeList)
{
    XmlNode id = node.FirstChild;
    XmlNode start = id.NextSibling;
    XmlNode end = start.NextSibling;
    XmlNode code = end.NextSibling;
}
```

I want to fill the array with the order [code][id][start][end]

In the XML Document there are many IDs for one code and for each ID there is 1 start and 1 end. 
So I do not know the number of codes and not the number of IDs

XML File Snippet:

```
<file>
     <ALL_INSTANCES>
          <instance>
               <ID>1</ID>
               <start>213.5000000000</start>
               <end>223.5000000000</end>
               <code>Bert</code>
               <label>
                    <text>Bert Doe</text>
               </label>
          </instance>
          <instance>
               <ID>2</ID>
               <start>213.5000000000</start>
               <end>231.3900001049</end>
               <code>John</code>
               <label>
                    <text>John Doe</text>
               </label>
               <label>
                    <text>Cross</text>
               </label>
          </instance>
          <instance>
               <ID>3</ID>
               <start>214.0000000000</start>
               <end>225.0000000000</end>
               <code>Passing</code>
          </instance>
          ....
     </ALL_INSTANCES>
</file>
```

Thanks for your help! :)

P.S.: In the end I have to fill a dropdown menu (in unity) where the user can choose between the codes and then I print out the IDs and their start and end.
If there is a better solution than an array I would love to know it :-)

Comment: I'd suggest two things: a) use a `List<T>` rather than an array, so you don't need to know the size up front. b) Write your own class with Code/Id/Start/End properties instead of using just a string array. It'll be much easier to work with the data that way.

Comment: Post xml.  It is easier to do this with Xml Linq which is a newer Net Library version of the Xml library.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm really new to C# so I'M not that familiar with List<T>. Are there multidimensional Lists so I can store many IDs for each code or how do you mean to use List<T> ? What should I write in the new class instead of the string array?

Comment: @jdweng I added a snippet of the XML document. Does Xml Linq also work with Unity because the script which I'm using is a script which is executed with Unity

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: Jon is suggesting that, instead of an array of strings, you declare a class such as this:

```
class Event
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public float Start { get; set; }
    public float End { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

and then declare a list like this:

```
var events = new List<Event>();
```

and then add your data to it like so:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in myNodeList)
{
    XmlNode id = node.FirstChild;
    XmlNode start = id.NextSibling;
    XmlNode end = start.NextSibling;
    XmlNode code = end.NextSibling;

    var event = new Event
    {
        Id = id,
        Start = start,
        End = end,
        Code = code
    };

    events.Add(event);
}
```

That way you will end up with a nice list of strongly-typed objects that's easy to work with, and won't have to worry about growing it because `List<T>` grows as you add stuff to it.

Note that this code won't work out of the box, the compiler will flag an error because you have to use the `XmlNode.Value` property in the first place and then, since it returns a string, convert `start` and `end` to `float`. Fixing it is left as an exercise for you. You have to figure out how to convert from `string` to `float`, Google will help with that.

Once you've learned that, look into LINQ to XML, which makes reading XML documents a breeze (though you will still have to do some type conversions manually).

By the way, I declared those two properties as `float`, but if by any chance you really really care about precision, you should declare them as `decimal`.

All credit to Jon Skeet, of course.

The code above here is not tested at all, try it out and make all the appropriate fixes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some problems with the "var event". If I put it in my code it always says something like "the name "var" is not available in the current context". What does that mean exactly? Am I missing a library?
I'm using the following libraries: System.Collections, System.Collections.Generic, System.IO, System.Xml, UnityEngine

Comment: @asgart what version of the .net framework are you on?

Comment: @asgart weird. Replace var with Event.

Comment: Then it says "'Event' is 'type' and in the stated context not valid" :-\
Could it be that the problem is Unity?

Comment: @asgart oh, it might. I'm sorry, I know nothing about it :(

Comment: I got the problem. The problem was the name of the var. The name cannot be "event" because event is a keyword and cannot be used as a name.

Comment: @asgart I'm sorry, I was in a hurry and didn't try to compile it, and the fact that it was "event" didn't ring a bell either :(